# Xquery sum of values

Tags: sum, xquery, xquery-3.0

I've got this part of code:

```
<recipe>
{ for $r in doc("retete.xml")//recipe
return <rec title="{$r/title}">{
<item>{
    for $r3 in doc("listaPreturi.xml")//produs
    for $r2 in $r/ingredients/ingredient
    where $r2/@name = $r3/@denumire
    return <it>{$r3/pret * $r2/@amount / $r3/pret/@cantitate}</it>
}
</item>
}</rec>}
</recipe>
```

And the result is this

```
<recipe>
 <rec title="Pui la cuptor">
   <item>
     <it>1550</it>
     <it>250</it>
  </item>
</rec>
<rec title="Curcan la cuptor">
  <item>
     <it>1550</it>
     <it>1889.9999999999998</it>
    </item>
  </rec>
</recipe>
```

How can I add in same function values for each `<it>` different `<item>` ?

Comment: Please complete the sentence: "Same function values for each different ___."  (There is a missing word.) What is the desired output?  You may need to supply retete.xml and listaPreturi.xml.

Comment: Also, what is the maximum version of xQuery your system can handle? Features(and solutions available to you) may vary based on this.

Comment: I've no idea from your question what you want to achieve, but I strongly suspect that in `/ $r3/pret/@cantitate` you want a division operator, `div`, not the path operator `/`